# WP8.1 screenshot not working

Tags: 8.1, lumia-925, screenshot

The keypresses to take a screenshot on Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia 925) are not working for me.

If I hold Volume Up and press Power, the screen goes blank (as if I just pressed Power on its own).

If I hold Power and press Volume Up, I get the Slide Down To Power Off option.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Volume Up and Power at the same time, rather than holding one of them down first?

Comment: Does your Volume Up button work otherwise? Possibly it's broken...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timing has to be quite good - you have to press <kbd>volume up</kbd> and <kbd>power</kbd> at the same time - if the presses are too far apart in time, it will treat the press as the first button you pressed, rather than taking a screenshot.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at the same time"? I can hold down either button, and press the other up to a half-second later, and it still registers. (I realize half a second isn't a terribly long time, but for something like this, it is rather long.)

Comment: I mean "close enough to fall within the tolerance that the devloper chose for this" - on my phone, my estimate of half a second results in the volume turning up, or the screen going off...

Comment: Half a second seems too long on my 925, but pressing the two buttons at precisely the same time is now working, thanks!

Comment: @RowlandShaw Well my half-second might not be quite right :)

Comment: I am pressing the buttons at the sametime but its telling me couldn't take screenshot i need urgent help please

Answer (score 3):

Use your two fingers to do this. The tolerance for pressing the both keys should be less than your current situation.

Answer (score 1):

It may take a little practice, because you can't hold one button and then press the other, even for a millisecond. 
I use two hands, and click both the power button and volume up button together rather firmly at the **exact** same time, as if it'one.